# Add a loading gif to my loadmore jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a load more button, and now I want to add a loading more gif to it so a user realizes it is running for the 1-2 seconds it takes to get the data.  This is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageNum = 2;
$(document).on('click', '#loadmore', function() {
     $.get('/loadmore.php?page=' + pageNum + '&aid=4', function(data) {
     $("#append").append(data);
        if(data){
            pageNum++; 
        }else{
            $('#loadmore').hide();  
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

How would i go about adding a gif that appears only while the data is being loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your loader gif using HTML:

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader{background:url(spinner.gif) no-repeat;display:none}
```

Add a reference in the beginning of your JS:

```
var gif = $('.loader');
```

Then work with it before & after the ajax function is completed:

```
gif.show(); // show the spinner
$.get('/loadmore.php?page=' + pageNum + '&aid=4', function(data) {
    gif.hide(); // hide it when the ajax request is completed
```

Answer (score 3):

just create a gif e.g. on http://ajaxload.info/ and put it after your button and hide it, only show it when you are acessing your funktion and hide it after ajax sucess